# Barometer on apple watch 4 ( is working?)

Tags: swift, watch, core-motion

I have the below code working on the iPhone, but for the life of me I can't seem to get any data back when running it on the apple watch.  Any suggestions?

```
    // works on phone, not on watch
    // get pressure readings  and sace for later display
    if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
        altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data, error) in
            self.myAltitudePressureMetric = String.init(format: "%.1fM", (data?.relativeAltitude.floatValue)!)

            self.myAltitudePressureFeet = String.init(format: "%.1fft", (data?.relativeAltitude.floatValue)! * 3.6)

            self.myPressurehPa = String.init(format: "%.2f hPA", (data?.pressure.floatValue)!*10)


        }
    } else {
        myAltitudePressureFeet = " no pressure data"
        myAltitudePressureMetric = " no pressure data"
    }
```

Comment: Did you Check CMAltimeter.authorizationStatus()

Comment: Check out this project to see if you can find the difference. [Barometer](https://github.com/mwcs01/Barometer)

Answer (score -1):

My bad.

I defined  altimeter = CMAltimeter()  inside

func awake(withContext context: Any?

rather than just inside

class InterfaceController4: WKInterfaceController

It now works!   Thanks for the suggestions.